# Jupyter NB prevents Javascript execution from taking effect

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, javascript-objects, dygraphs

I am running a jupyter notebook on a local server and spent the entire last day trying to get a javascript library for charting to run. It's called Dygraph (http://dygraphs.com/). Outside of the jupyter notebook everything is working as it should, but if I want to use the library inside a notebook, then things get messy. Even displaying a simple html file, which uses the library and works just fine outside jupyter, is not working when viewed via the server. All resources are in the right place and seem to get executed, just without having a lasting effect.

I know that the script is executed, because I appended "console.log('okay')" to the local source file (http://dygraphs.com/2.1.0/dygraph.min.js) and "okay" is in fact showing up in the browser console.

I executed the script in the following ways (none of which were effective):

1. By using IPython to paste a script tag, which links to the resource (src="...")
2. By reading the content of the script using python and using IPython to execute the javascript directly
3. The most obvious way: by manually copy-pasting the content of
   dygraph.min.js into the console

If I execute 3) on any other site, then I can successfully run the following simple statement:

```
console.log(Dygraph)
```

However when I am inside the notebook and try the same, I instead just get:

```
ReferenceError: Dygraph is not defined
```

How is this possible and how to fix it?

PS:
I also tried using the python wrapper PyDyGraphs (https://github.com/DayStarEngineering/PyDyGraphs). The example code of the github page throws the same ReferenceError and the graph is not displayed correctly (instead there is just the empty div).